# pjsip change contact sip address within the router enabled ALG

Tags: router, pjsip, gateway

While developing iOS PJSIP client, I found that PJSIP would change contact address at second register request with authorization. It only happens when I enable ALG feature on my router, and the router will drop all response packets after first ack packet.

For example, disable ALG

[image]

enable ALG

[image]

PJSIP version: 2.7.1

How can I lock PJSIP contact sip address when ALG is enable?

Comment: Please paste the actual logs into the body of your question, and format them using the StackOverflow's markdown. Questions with images of logs/exceptions tend to get voted down.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off the [allow_contact_rewrite](http://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/structpjsua__acc__config.htm#a22961bb72ea75f7ca7008464f081ca06) feature in the account configuration.

This should stop pjsip from modifying the contact header on registration.